# Calculating a field based on totals from queries in MS Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

First time posting. Reader for some time now. This site has answered every question I have ever had! However, I ran into a problem that I simply cannot find the answer to.

I am new to Access but I am doing OK in a project at work. Here is the background:

We send surveys to clients scoring the associate that talked to them from 1-10. Once I receive them, I input them in a table called tblSurveys with an id of the employee they talked to. There is another table that has the employeeID, the name of the employee and their Supervisor's ID. There is yet another table with the SupervisorID, the name of the supervisor, and the regional manager's ID. Last table includes the RegionalManagerID and the name of the Regional Manager. They are then related in Access. Primary keys are the IDs for each group and the Surveys have an autonumber called SurveyID.

Hope it all makes sense.

The way that we score the employees is based on the results of the survey: a 1-6 is a "Detractor" which counts as -1, a 9-10 is a "Promoter" which counts as +1. We add these numbers and then divide by the total number of surveys. For example:

I get 5 survey results: 10, 10, 10, 5, 8. The score would be (3-1)/5 = 40% because there are 3 "Promoters", 1 "Detractor", and a total of 5 surveys. Cool.

Going back to the problem.

I am trying to get a query that results in a list of each employee and their respective score (from the calculation above). I thought I could simply use three queries, one asking to count how many Detractors per employee, another for total Promoters per employee and another one for total surveys per employee.
How can I create a query that spits out the darn calculation after then? I have been stuck on this for two days now.

Once I get that working, I need to do the same but apply it per supervisor, then per Regional Manager.

Then I need a report that essentially lists the total score for the whole company, then score per regional manager, then score per supervisor then score per employee. (Like nested)

How can I accomplish this?

Best regards,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using multiple queries as individual reports and as data sources.

Suppose your tables looks like this...

tblSurveys:

```
employeeid    score
----------    -----
1             10
2             3
2             2
3             7

etc...
```

tblEmployees:

```
employeeid    EmployeeName    SupervisorId    
----------    -------------   ------------    
1             Employee 1      1               

etc...
```

tblSupervisors:

```
SuperVisorId   SuperVisorName   RegManagerId
------------   --------------   -------------
1              Super 1          1
2              Super 2          1

etc...
```

tblRegManagers:

```
RegManagerId    RegManagerName
-------------   -----------------
1               Regional Manager 1
2               Regional Manager 2

etc...
```

You may be able to create multipurpose queries. See SQL below...

Query1: This gives you the employee stats

```
select SupervisorName,RegManagerId,EmployeeName,
    Promoter,Detractor,surveys,Promoter-Detractor AS score,
    (Promoter-Detractor)/surveys as result 
    from 
    (       
    select a.EmployeeName,b.SupervisorName, b.RegManagerId,
    (select count(*) from tblSurveys where 
    employeeid=a.employeeid and score<7) as Detractor,
    (select count(*) from tblSurveys where 
    employeeid=a.employeeid and score>6)  as Promoter,
    (select count(*) from tblSurveys where employeeid=a.employeeid) as surveys 
    from tblEmployees a left join tblSupervisors b on a.supervisorid=b.supervisorid
    )
```

Query2: This gives you the supervisor stats but also uses employee stats (Query1)

```
select supervisorname,RegManagerId, 
    promotersum, detractorsum, surveyssum,(promotersum-detractorsum)/surveyssum 
    from 
    (select SuperVisorName,RegManagerId, sum(Promoter) as PromoterSum, 
    sum(Detractor) as DetractorSum, 
    sum(surveys) as surveyssum from query1 group by SuperVisorName,RegManagerId )
```

Query3: This gives you Regional Manager stats but also uses supervisor stats (Query2)

```
select RegManagerName, promoter_cnt, detractor_cnt, survey_cnt, promoter_cnt-detractor_cnt as score, 
    (promoter_cnt-detractor_cnt)/survey_cnt as result 
    from 
    (select a.RegManagerName, b.RegManagerId, sum(b.promotersum) as promoter_cnt, 
    sum(b.detractorsum) as detractor_cnt, sum(b.surveyssum) as survey_cnt 
    from tblRegManagers a left join query2 b on a.RegManagerId=b.RegManagerId 
    group by a.RegManagerName, b.RegManagerId)
```

So, while each query serves as a report by themselves, the first two are used as source queries.

Comment: This is what I originally thought: subqueries. But I am not certain on how to use them at all. I will try it though.

Comment: This is awesome! I have it working almost perfectly. The only thing I wanted to ask you is regarding the RegionalManagerID. You added it on Query 1 however the way I have the actual tables is a bit different: tblEmployees does not have the RegionalManagerID. The tblSupervisors is the one that actually has the RegionalManagerID as the third column. Because of this, how can I modify the first SQL code to include the RegionalManagerID since the beginning?

Comment: Glad to hear this helped you. On Query1, change `a.RegManagerId` to `b.RegManagerId`. Try that. Also, please vote up the answer if this was useful.

Comment: I have revised my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be over-thinking the problem - you can do the whole Promoter/Detractor score thing in one query.  You would need an aggregate subquery, with a field: `Score:Sum(Choose([SurveyResult],-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,0,1,1))/Count(*)`.  Add an `EmployeeID` field to `Group By`.

Since Choose returns a value based on an input integer (which in my example then gets summed), it is pretty much ideal for this situation.  Just divide by the number of survey results (`Count(*)`) to get the score.

Save this in its own query, then use it as a subquery in your main query, joined on `EmployeeID`

Comment: Very interesting approach. I will certainly try this tomorrow. I will be back with the results.

Comment: I am very new to Access and SQL. What would be the code if we used the Tables seen in the other response?